# Subdomain to AppEngine Application w/ CloudFare

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cpanel, cloudflare

I'm using cloudfare, and I have the record below:

```
Type        Name        Value               TTL         Active
A           mysubdomain to my webhost IP    Automatic   not
```

In cpanel, I have:

```
mysubdomain.example.com.    CNAME   ghs.google.com
```

The problem is that when I try to access my subdomain in browser, I was redirected to `/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`

What's wrong w/ my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an A record and a CNAME record for the same name pointing at different things. This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to point to an A record to your IP for the subdomain if you're actually using Google for that subdomain (how I'm reading this). It would generally look like this, if you are:

CNAME subdomain name is an alias of ghs.google.com